Isolated DC-DC converter Baseplate grounding
I am planning to use an isolated DC-DC converter from VICOR to create two ground reference for the input and output side of the converter for a circuit requirement. The input and output pins of the converter are recommended to be bypassed to converter baseplate which is recommended to be tied to earth ground (datasheet link below).
https://www.vicorpower.com/documents/datasheets/ds_vi-200.pdf
I am planning to use a DC power supply with floating outputs (positive and negative) to connect to the IN+ and IN- pin of the isolated converter. The power supply has a separate GND terminal marked green, which I assume is the Earth potential. Can I connect the baseplate of the converter to this GND terminal and achieve the objective of keeping input ground, output ground and baseplate ground separate without creating any ground loop or other issues?

The bypass capacitors shown in the datasheet are for common mode noise filtering. If the system has a common node (such as earth) then it can be beneficial to use the bypass capacitors for optimum performance. It's suggested in the design guide that the bypass capacitors must be used even if there's no EMC consideration. With the bypass capacitors connected, the input and output will still be kept isolated (unless the capacitors are too large).

Can I connect the baseplate of the converter to this GND terminal and achieve the objective of keeping input ground, output ground and baseplate ground separate without creating any ground loop or other issues?

No details of your DC supply are given but if it's an off-line (taking the input from mains), isolated DC power source with an earth connection then yes, you can.
Note that the earth connection is meaningful when it is the common node for the system i.e. both input connections must be referenced to this common node. For example, in mains electrical system, both L (live) and N (neutral) voltages are referenced to the earth (PE / protective earth) so the earth is a common node. Even if your DC power supply has its output isolated from mains, there's still going to be some leakage therefore both terminals of the DC output can still be considered earth-referenced.
If your DC supply was a completely isolated source such as a car battery then the earth connection would be meaningless as it'd be no different than a floating piece of metal.
